# Querying rows by attribute or by existance in JOIN table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the entities A and B (with their respective tables). Those entities have a N:M relationship, so there is an AB table.

The A entity has a `disabled` boolean field.

I want to get all entities from A that (`are not disabled` OR `are in the AB table and belong to B entity with id 1`) using ActiveRecord.

Example:

```
A  
| id | name | disabled |
| a1 | foo  | false    |
| a2 | bar  | false    |
| a3 | zoo  | true     |
| a4 | hoo  | true     |

B
| id | name |
| 1  | Bob  |
| 2  | Jen  |

AB
|Aid | Bid |
| a3 | 1   |
```

`A` entities for Bob: `foo`, `bar` ans `zoo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A.includes(:bs).where('as.disabled = false OR bs.id = 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

`A.where(:disabled => false )` will find all the entries from A that are not disabled and `B.find_by_id(1).as` will find all the entries from A that belong to B entity with id 1. `A.where(:disabled => false ) | B.find_by_id(1).as` taking OR of the 2 arrays gives the required entries.

`requeried_entries = A.where(:disabled => false ) | B.find_by_id(1).as`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: `A.where(:disabled => false )` will find all the entries from A that are not disabled and `B.find_by_id(1).as` will find all the entries from A that belong to B entity with id 1.  `A.where(:disabled => false ) | B.find_by_id(1).as` taking OR of the 2 arrays gives the required entries.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add the description of what your code does and why it should be used. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier.